# The edit button isn't working on SO

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was on Stack Overflow just now editing someone else's question. When I submitted it, there was a queue on the edit, so my edit didn't go through. So I went back to leave the editing process. By doing that, I can't edit anyone's work. I finding that really annoying. [image: Error of picture]

Comment: Hover over the gray edit button to see why you can't edit.

Comment: If you have an issue with Stack Overflow, the question needs to go on the SO meta...

Comment: @Catija: It has nothing to do with SO and everything to do with the SE software.

Comment: @NathanTuggy so? Half of the questions I see on the various site metas are exactly that.

Comment: @Catija: Standard practice is that if someone wants to ask on the local meta about a problem that's actually universal, that's fine, but if they ask on MSE it's also fine, unless it actually *isn't* universal at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard said:

> Hover over the gray edit button to see why you can't edit.

It's not that it's not working or we'll all notice that issue at some point. It is probably one of two reasons with the latter being highly unlikely if you have a low edit rejection rate:

- The post has a pending (suggested) edit that still needs to be reviewed
- You have an editing ban

The first reason is probably the more likely reason here of course if you can edit other posts but just not that one.

Comment: @Catija Fixed that issue

Comment: It can also be because you already have 5 suggested edits pending (you can't suggest more than 5 edits at a time).